# Can you animate and change perspective of textures in real time and have textures that follow camera view?

Tags: animation, texturing, normals, 2d, npr

I want to be able to change the perspective of a texture and animate it. I know you can put a 2d rig onto a 3d model, but in tutorials you have to import a 2d image of each frame (or in a face rig, "expressions" of a model) for that method. I want to use a texture as plane and use sort of a double exposure technique onto the main mesh, while changing the angle of the plane mesh acting as the texture for the main mesh in real time. The plane mesh should also not be affected by any environment light or scene lights, so in a way be unlit to maintain the original color of the texture as much as possible.
If you look at 2d shows like monster high or ever after high, and focus on their clothing texture and how they act, that is the effect I want.
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lV3QOFYUxiU&pp=ygUPRXZlciBhZnRlciBoaWdo
Their clothing texture kinda follows the camera view, but it is also not completely static, and I haven't seen any way to do this in blender. It is like a mix of window texture coordinates and the texture actually following the mesh. Also similar to normal editing for anime styles, but this time for textures instead. I also wanted a way to a apply this effect for meshes shrink-wrapped to the surface of the main mesh.
[image]

See how the texture do not follow the clothes' volume while still being lively/bouncy?

From another forum (blenderartists), someone gave some ideas:

"Basically a first step would be to be able to get the bounding box of an object in screen space, which means it’s always facing the camera.

Then it’s just a matter of mapping the texture according to that, maybe by transferring the texture coordinate of that bounding box to the geometry.

Another thing to account for is how different the camera angles are, say if your object is always facing the camera the same way,it’s much simpler, but if you start to do up and down camera angles things get much more complex."

I found a tutorial a bit of a starting point for this:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=RrtGmzkp-CA&t=332s
It is a starting point, but in the video, the bounding box still uses the uv coordinates in a way that wraps around the mesh, still giving a 3d look.